# how to convert object array to double array in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Hello recently i am trying get the result using matlab function and matlab function can return double array like image but and then I got that double by object class in C# but I could not convert to double that object class
some one could help me

I have solved this problem

```
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
        matlab.Execute(@"Path");
        object result = null;
        matlab.Feval("RemoveShadow", 1, out result, 12, 13);
        var res = (result as object[]).Select(x => (double[,])x).ToArray();
        object im = res.GetValue(0);
        double[,] d = (double[,])im;
```

I have solved this problem

Comment: Try doing a `result.GetType()` to see its exact type (in the debugger or doing `Console.WriteLine(result.GetType())` if you are doing a console program)

Comment: *but I could not convert to double that object class* What didn't work? did you receive an error message?

Comment: I have recived the"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in program.exe "

Comment: If you are getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` That means that you are trying to access an index that does not exist in the array. I notice that you are calling `res[1]`. Are we sure that has a value? Arrays have a zero based index, which means the first element is at index 0 not index 1

Comment: I am glad that you have fixed your problem. But never, update your question with answer. Either  mark one of the asnwers as answer or add your own answer and mark this. Thanks. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

if all are double in object array than, alternative to above answer

```
double[] resultArray = Array.ConvertAll<object, double>
                                  (inputArray, x => (double)x);
```

Comment: i need this array  double[,]

Comment: Thank you I have got result

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to convert `object[]` to `double[]`:

```
var res = (result as object[]).Select(x => (double)x).ToArray();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but object class does not have Select method

Answer (score -1):

Correct way to handle this is

var res = (result as object[]).Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x)).ToArray();

Comment: I tried his code and it didnt worked , I got InvalidTypeCaste exception because sometimes array might be having null. So above given solution have issue while handling null. where as if we use my solution you can control null type casting.